# SELECT xyz INTO #Temp from SSMS is 5x longer in one environment than another

Tags: sql-server, performance, latch

First time posting, I hope I'm doing it right.

I'm a "dba by accident" who is learning a lot but admittedly still has a lot more to learn. Here is my brain dump:

1. Prod server has 5 million rows. I copied those rows to a Test server.
2. Using SNAPSHOT or READ UNCOMMITTED produce different elapsed times, but the ratio between Prod and Test is always ~5:1 (14 minutes:3 minutes with SNAPSHOT, 4 minutes:sub-1 with READ UNCOMMITTED)
3. Using STATISTICS IO ON reveals that most of the reads on Prod are logical (~90%) while none of the reads on Test are logical. I **think** that should mean Prod would be faster if anything.
4. Most of the time appears to be going to waits of type "PAGEIOLATCH_SH."
5. I don't **think** different statistics can matter, since no index should be used on an unfiltered, unjoined, unsorted query.
6. SELECTing the top n rows on both servers reveals a very linear scale... the ratio is always ~5:1.
7. The comparison is not apples-to-apples, but I think the only relevant differences are activity and storage.
8. I have performed the comparison when activity was next to nothing, and saw the same results.
9. I discovered that autogrowth was set to 1MB (ugh), which I have since changed but I wonder if this has led to fragmented storage at the file system level.
10. The database is on a separate volume from the Windows installation, but it does share a volume with tempdb and with a FILESTREAM store, which I **assume** could also lead to fragmented storage.
11. The "optimize drives" windows utility says the volume is "OK (98% space efficiency)" which seems to suggest that maybe file system fragmentation isn't a problem.

Questions:

Are my **thoughts** and **assumptions** above correct?

Is there anything I'm blatantly overlooking in my thought process?

What are good candidates for the next steps in this troubleshooting process?

What other information can/should I have provided?

Thank you for your attention and help!

EDIT: Added rest of time information in 2nd statement.

Comment: Are you saying prod is *slower* or *faster* than the non-prod environment?  Is hardware the same across environments?

Comment: Hi Max! Prod is _slower_ than the non-prod environment. Hardware is comparable.

Comment: You mentioned that the database shares a volume with tempdb and a file stream store. Is the SQL server installation/configuration the same on the non-prod environment as the prod server?  Are both environments consuming roughly the same amount of memory for SQL server?

Comment: What version and edition of sql server are you using ? What is the Total RAM, CPU, max memory and max DOP settings on both PROD and non-prod servers ? You want to optimize the `SELECT xyz INTO #Temp` for 5 million rows transferring them from PROD to non-PROD ?

Comment: Aaron - Yes, the installation/configuration is the same. The same amount of memory is allocated, but is probably not as taxed in the non-production environment.

Comment: Kin - Version/edition: SELECT @@VERSION gives "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
 Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)".

Comment: Total RAM is 14GB, with min/max of 10GB allocated to SQL (leaving the rest for system). CPU is 2.2 GHz 4 cores (8 virtual). I had to look up what max DOP even was ( :-/  )  It is set to 0. My goal is **not** to optimize for the selection of 5 million rows, nor to transfer data from PROD to non-PROD. I just observed that the closest I have come to apples-to-apples (regardless of volume) suggests a fundamental issue.

Comment: Are you using "Insert Into"? Are you using temp tables? What is the recovery model of databases? Is tempDB configured the same on both environments?

Comment: Hi Jānis - yes, I am using INSERT INTO (with a temp table) to avoid SSMS's UI bottlenecking the query. The recovery model is full, but I'm curious how that could relate. tempDB is configured similarly, but is probably not as "abused" in the non-PROD environment as it is in the PROD environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it sounds like issue with tempdb.. What you could do- check how many files you have on each server- you can see recommendations [here](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/tempdb-performance-and-configuration/).

Are they big enough and not growing when you doing inserts? What about log file of tempdb?
if they are growing- best would be to expand them before (and keep that way).

One more thing you can check- if they are growing, you can probably make it faster by using [instant file initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx).

Comment: Jānis, thank you. The tempdb had just one single file. I changed it per the recommendations you referred me to, and it worked wonders. The ratio in my testing has gone from 5:1 to 1.2:1. It appears that instant file initialization is not an option because the db uses TDE. However, with this out of the way I can feel better about troubleshooting and optimizing the database in general. Thank you so so much... this may have seemed trivial to you, but it wasn't to me :-)